# How to pass an argument through a button in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, python-idle

I am trying to make a basic programme in Python 3.7 for a school project that, when a button is pressed, prints a string of text. Anyone have any ideas on what I have done wrong please?

I've tried using a lambda function but it gives me an error message.

```
#This is what I have tried:

import tkinter

window = tkinter.Tk()
button1 = tkinter.Button(window, text = "Press Me1", command= lambda: action("1"))
button2 = tkinter.Button(window, text = "Press Me2", command= lambda: action("2"))
button1.pack()
button2.pack()
window.mainloop()

if button1 == "1":
    print("Button 1 was pressed.")
elif button2 == "2":
    print("Button 2 was pressed.")

I'm expecting that, when you press one of the buttons, it prints the specified statement.

#However, I get the following error message:

Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "C:\Users\liamd\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1705, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
    File "C:\Users\liamd\Documents\!!!!MY STUFF!!!!\Python\Bankaccount Assessment - Simplified - And Again.py", line 4, in <lambda>
    button1 = tkinter.Button(window, text = "Press Me1", command= lambda: action("1"))
NameError: name 'action' is not defined
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another way to do this is to define specific functions for when the buttons are pressed. If you plan to have other things happen on button pressing then this can be helpful.

```
import tkinter

#This is what I added to get the buttons to work.
def on_button_1():
    print('Button 1 was pressed.')
def on_button_2():
    print('Button 2 was pressed.')


window = tkinter.Tk()
#changed these next 2 lines so that each button calls the appropriate function
button1 = tkinter.Button(window, text = "Press Me1", command= on_button_1)
button2 = tkinter.Button(window, text = "Press Me2", command= on_button_2)
button1.pack()
button2.pack()
window.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to provide an implementation for your `action` function, before calling it, for instance:

```
def action(message):
    print(message)
```

So your code would look like this:

```
import tkinter

def action(message):
    print(message)

window = tkinter.Tk()
button1 = tkinter.Button(window, text = "Press Me1", command= lambda: action("Button 1 was pressed"))
button2 = tkinter.Button(window, text = "Press Me2", command= lambda: action("Button 2 was pressed"))
button1.pack()
button2.pack()
window.mainloop()
```

or alternatively, you can replace all your `action` calls with `print()` calls:

```
button1 = tkinter.Button(window, text = "Press Me1", command= lambda: print("Button 1 was pressed"))
button1 = tkinter.Button(window, text = "Press Me1", command= lambda: print("Button 2 was pressed"))
```

The `if` conditions will not do anything, because they are not triggered by a button press.